# C# ¿Cómo concatenar carácter "," de manera dinámica en un update?

Tags: c#

Tengo un `update` dinámico, que solo actualiza los campos cuando una variable tiene valor `true`, de la siguiente manera:

```
string s_miVariable;
string s_miVariable3;
string miVariable;
string miVariable2;
string miVariable3;
string miVariable4;
string miVariable5;
string miVariable6;
Boolean b_miVariable = false;
Boolean b_miVariable3 = false;
Boolean b_miVariable5 = false;

if (miVariable == miVariable2)
{
    //Paso 1.
    s_miVariable = "";
    b_miVariable = false;
}
else
{
    //Paso 2.
    s_miVariable = " nombreCampo = " + "'" + valorCampo + "'";
    b_miVariable = true;

}
if (miVariable3 == miVariable4)
{
    //Paso 1.
    s_miVariable3 = "";
    b_miVariable3 = false;
}
else
{
    //Paso 2.
    s_miVariable3 = " nombreCampo = " + "'" + valorCampo + "'";
    b_miVariable3 = true;

}
if (miVariable5 == miVariable6)
{
    //Paso 1.
    s_miVariable3 = "";
    b_miVariable3 = false;
}
else
{
    //Paso 2.
    s_miVariable3 = " nombreCampo = " + "'" + valorCampo + "'";
    b_miVariable3 = true;

}



if (b_miVariable == true ||b_miVariable3 == true ||b_miVariable5 == true  )
    string Update = "UPDATE nombreTabla SET " +
    //variable con campo y valor concatenado
    s_miVariable 
    +s_miVariable3 
    +s_miVariable5 +
    "' WHERE campoN = '" + campoN +"";
```

El problema es que si yo concateno en *"Paso 2"* una `","` y el campo anterior no tiene nada, me marcará un error. Si alguien conoce alguna manera de concatenar un carácter `","` en este caso, solo cuando `b_miVarible == true` sería genial si lo pudieran compartir, gracias.

Comment: No comprendo para qué necesitas una coma, con el código que muestras, esa coma que pretendes concatenar siempre va a estar de más, pues siempre se actualiza un único campo.

Comment: He añadido algo de código para ver si logro explicarme mejor. Suponiendo que de los tres campos de arriba solo el 2do. y el 3ro. venga cargado de un valor, si concateno la coma al inicio de cada campo, en el 2do. la ", " sobraria. Lo mismo si la concateno al final y solo el 1ro. y el 2do vienen cargados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero tomar un enfoque algo diferente, no necesitas tantas variables de control ni tantas variables con fragmentos del *SQL*. Puedes lograrlo con una única variable con el fragmento *SQL* de todos los campos a actualizar, lo cual también simplifica la lógica de cuándo agregar la coma.

La idea es inicializar esta variable en blanco, e ir concatenándole los fragmentos a medida que vas comparando las variables que tienen los datos, solo si hace falta.

Te puedes basar en el valor de esa variable (si está vacía o no) para decidir si concatenar una coma y finalmente también para decidir si hay que lanzar la sentencia contra la base de datos.

Para decidir si concatenar una coma en cada caso, puedes utilizar el [operador ternario `?`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator), solo a partir del segundo campo. En el primero, sabemos de antemano que no hace falta ninguna coma.

En código, sería algo como:

```
string sSQL = "";

if (miVariable != miVariable2) {
  sSQL = "nombreCampo = " + "'" + valorCampo + "'";
}
if (miVariable3 != miVariable4) {
  sSQL += (sSQL != "" ? ", " : "") + "nombreCampo2 = " + "'" + valorCampo2 + "'";
}
if (miVariable5 != miVariable6) {
  sSQL += (sSQL != "" ? ", " : "") + "nombreCampo3 = " + "'" + valorCampo3 + "'";
}
if (sSQL != "") {
  string sqlUpdate = "UPDATE nombreTabla SET " 
    + sSQL 
    + " WHERE campoN = '" + campoN +"'";
  EjecutarSQL(sqlUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Buen día! Ok, si, entiendo a lo que te refieres, voy a probar y vuelvo para comentar.

Answer (score 0):

una forma de concatenar es seria solo verificar si hay datos en tu cadena utilizando el el operador ?: en el cual se verifica si hay datos

ejemplo:

```
s_miVariable = ((b_miVariable==true)?",":"")+" nombreCampo = " + "'" + valorCampo + "'";
```

no se entiende bien tu problema, ya que en tu código solo entraría una

Comment: Hola Juan Carlos, he añadido algo de código para ver si logro explicarme mejor.      Suponiendo que de los tres campos de arriba solo el 2do. y el 3ro. venga cargado de un valor, si concateno la coma al inicio de cada campo, en el  2do.  la ", " sobraria. Lo mismo si la concateno al final y solo el 1ro. y el 2do vienen cargados. No sé si he conseguido explicarme?